# How to align a QComboBox vertically on Mac OS X in Qt 4

Tags: css, macos, qt, qt4, qt4.8

I have a horizontal layout containing a QLabel, QComboBox and QLineEdit. I looks fine on Windows. But on Mac OS X the QComboBox vertical alignment is off.

[image: red lines added by me]

(red lines added by me)

So I tried changing the QComboBox stylesheet:

```
lineEdit->setStyleSheet( "QLineEdit{ margin-top: 3px; }" );
```

That looks better:

[image]

But the QLineEdit focus rectangle looks all wrong:

[image]

(Note the gap at the top of the focus rect).

I know its not a big deal. But it looks wrong and its irking me!

I am using Qt 4.8.6 on Mac OS X 10.10.

Comment: How about adding bottom margin to the QComboBox instead?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't look right.